# Start and stop multiple processes via bash script at once

Tags: node.js, bash, terminal

I'm writing a simple bash script to spin up multiple services to be able to have a local development environment started easily with a single command

What I did is create a bash script that loops all subdirectories and starts them with the appropriate command (all my programs are `nodejs` and `angular` applications). I'd like to avoid hard-coding so each time I add a new service I can get it up and running automatically.

This is what I wrote

```
for d in `ls -d */`
do
    ( cd $d 
      if [ ! -f bower.json ]; then # skip clients
        NODE_ENV=dev node index &
      fi
      if [ -f bower.json ]; then
        grunt serve &
      fi
    )
done
```

By using the `&` operator I'm able to start all processes, by the way when I need to stop them I need to `ps -a` and kill them automatically.

I'd like to have all them stopped togheter when I `CTRL+C` the file.
Looking for some answer always took me an hard-coded solution where one always knows what commands, to be run.

In this case how many commands will be executed is not know until the `ls` command returns.

Is there a way to proper get processes handled as one or at least a way to store `pids` and then kill all of them at once (maybe with a SIGINT handler)?

Comment: You can probably get the pids of all of them by saying `pidof node`. Also, note that saying `for d in `ls -d */` can be simplified to `for d in */`.